# При увеличения табличного пространства ошибка: ORA-01144: Размер файла (13107200 блоков) превышает максимум 4194303 блоков

Tags: sql, oracle

Появилась необходимость увеличения табличного пространства `Users` путем создания нового .dbf размером в 100G.

Но получаю ошибку:

> ORA-01144: Размер файла (13107200 блоков) превышает максимум 4194303 блоков.

Тогда не понимаю, какой максимальный размер табличного пространства можно создать? Почему нельзя сделать его, к примеру, в 100GB? И что теперь, когда табличное пространство будет заканчиваться, мне нужно каждый раз создавать файлы меньшего размера?

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, всю ошибку целиком

Comment: @Viktorov добавил. Спасибо

Comment: а ваша файловая система вообще позволяет создавать файлы в 100гб ?

Comment: @Viktorov ну я думаю что да у меня стоит NTFS. Или я неправильно посчитал 2^64-1 ?

Comment: думаете или точно? Предлагаю попробовать создать 3 файла по 32 гб

Comment: еще гляньте http://www.runningoracle.com/product_info.php?products_id=338

Comment: @Viktorov думал, видимо не внимательно считал по пути домой. Спасибо за ответ. Если хотите оформите как ответ и я закрою тему.

Comment: Оформите сами :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Достигнут [лимит](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/physical-database-limits.html) по кол-ву блоков в файле данных:

> Database Blocks | Maximum per datafile | Platform dependent; typically 2^22 - 1 blocks

Если блок 8.196 байта:
`(2^22-1=4194303)*8192=34359730176` байтов‬ максимально, т.е. 32G - 1 блок.

Просто добавте ещё один, два, три ... файл(ов):

```
alter tablespace users add datafile '.../dbfiles/oradata/.../users03.dbf' size 32G;

ORA-01144: File size (4194304 blocks) exceeds maximum of 4194303 blocks

alter tablespace users add datafile '.../dbfiles/oradata/.../users03.dbf' size 34359730176;

Tablespace USERS altered.
```